# How come my order by section gives a 'not a group by' error

Tags: mysql

My SQL-query works fine until I add in the 'order by' clause.
I receive a 'not a group by expression' error
I thought you were supposed to put an exact copy of the column in the 'select' clause ,in the 'order by' clause if you wish to edit the order of said column in your table...

```
select 
case when latitude between -18 and 18 then 'tropical'
 when latitude between -36 and 36 then 'subtropical'
 when latitude between -54 and 54 then 'average'
 when latitude between -72 and 72 then 'subpolar'
 else 'polar' end klimaat,
count(1)
from regios
WHERE latitude is not null and niveau=0
group by case when latitude between -18 and 18 then 'tropical'
 when latitude between -36 and 36 then 'subtropical'
 when latitude between -54 and 54 then 'average'
 when latitude between -72 and 72 then 'subpolar'
 else 'polar' end
order by case when latitude between -18 and 18 then 5
 when latitude between -36 and 36 then 4
 when latitude between -54 and 54 then 3
 when latitude between -72 and 72 then 2
 else 1 end
```

EDIT: To clarify , I am not necessarily looking for a solution to this problem but rather an explanation on why this particular piece of code doesn't work

Comment: why not simply: order by abs(latitude) asc ? seems to me it would give same result.

Comment: also I do think mysql could use aliases in group by, like: select ... group by klimaat order by klimaat

Comment: I am not necessarily looking for a solution to this problem but rather an explanation on why this particular piece of code doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, with your CASE
 you create just one column.  In order by you can specify only column usually by name, but you can use number (position of the column in the select list).

Try

```
select 
case when latitude between -18 and 18 then 'tropical'
 when latitude between -36 and 36 then 'subtropical'
 when latitude between -54 and 54 then 'average'
 when latitude between -72 and 72 then 'subpolar'
 else 'polar' end klimaat,
count(1)
from regios
WHERE latitude is not null and niveau=0
group by case when latitude between -18 and 18 then 'tropical'
 when latitude between -36 and 36 then 'subtropical'
 when latitude between -54 and 54 then 'average'
 when latitude between -72 and 72 then 'subpolar'
 else 'polar' end
order by 1;
```

I did a test in mysql: it seems it works this too (for semplicity I just removed your AND niveau=0)

```
select 
case when latitude between -18 and 18 then 'tropical'
 when latitude between -36 and 36 then 'subtropical'
 when latitude between -54 and 54 then 'average'
 when latitude between -72 and 72 then 'subpolar'
 else 'polar' end klimaat,
count(1) AS RC
from regios
WHERE latitude is not null  
group by klimaat
order by klimaat;
```

Sample data:

```
create table regios (latitude integer, test varchar(100));
insert into regios value (15, 'aaa');
insert into regios value (37, 'bbb');
insert into regios value (55, 'ccc');
insert into regios value (84, 'ddd');
```

Output:

```
klimaat RC
1   average 1
2   polar   1
3   subpolar    1
4   tropical    1
```

If next time you post script to create table, sample data and obtained and expected results (in text form) all member of SO can help you better and faster.

Comment: Doesn't give the intentioned order. I am more looking for an explanation why my code doesn't work ,rather than a solution

Comment: see update for a simple explanation.   What order do you want?  It would be easier to help if you post sample data, expected result, etc. (as suggested by StackOverflow)

Comment: I'm guessing here but: the group by expression, even tho has exact case when end clause, is a second, ie different, expression than your select expression. in recent versions of mysql, by default, it is enforced that your group by and select columns have to be same (or with grouping functions like min/max etc). so, that might be giving the error.

Comment: so using the columnalias than actually makes sure that the column in the order by clause isn't misinterpreted as a new piece of code?

Comment: in Mysql it seems you can

Answer (score 0):

The expressions that are not encapsulated within an aggregate function must be included in the GROUP BY clause and only those which are encapsulated within an aggregate function can be used in an order by, unless you are using number position for the column.

So, In your example,the expression evaluated in the non-encapsulated column (klimaat) is different from the columns used in the ORDER BY clause.If you use MAX(latitude) in your ORDER BY , it will work because now it is encapsulated within an aggregate function.